# How to Tighten the Quality Ratchet with CI

Tags: c#, continuous-integration, resharper, cruisecontrol.net, stylecop

My team is in the process of getting Continuous Integration working with all of our projects. Right now we've got CruiseControl building all of the projects, which is...nice, but not really THAT big a deal. I'm seeing much more bang for our buck from NUnit, StyleCop and Code Analysis / Resharper.

But here's the thing I'm considering...so I turn on StyleCop for a project, and it has seven hojillion violations. And it's going to have seven hojillion violations until they're all fixed. In the meantime, do I just have a broken build? Doesn't this potentially obscure much more important build breakers?

It seems to me that what would be ideal would be a tightening ratchet on a project basis...Customer A is brand new, so every rule we have is enabled and breaks the build. Customer B is legacy, so their violations only trigger warnings, and we hope at some point we can tighten their ratchet all the way, like Customer A.

Does this concept exist in CI? How can I best implement it?

Comment: Does StyleCop have any granularity in how 'turned on' it is? File-by-file or warning-by-warning perhaps? Certainly warning-by-warning, if available, suggests an obvious incremental approach ("by the end of this week we will have got rid of Hungarian *and it will never be allowed back*", etc)

Comment: @AakashM - yeah, that's exactly what I'm thinking. It's probably more a "by severity" approach, so that most of the pain is experienced up front.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've not played with StyleCop, but with FxCop (another analysis tool from Microsoft) we create two different ruleset - one we use to fail the build, and one that won't.  The one that fails the build is a relatively small set of rules (unused code, undisposed fields, etc.)  The one that doesn't fail the build has things like spelling and casing - items that are not important enough to fix now (or have so many violations that it would take forever to fix them all.)

When the build runs it calls FxCop twice, once for each ruleset.  Since we use msbuild to run our tools, we set the "FailOnError" flag to false for our warning set.  This lets us see the results, but ccnet will not fail the build, regardless of how many violations we might have.

Comment: This is very helpful - in fact, I would appreciate it if you could elaborate on your dealbreaker FxCop ruleset...FxCop is the other tool we're looking to implement immediately.

Comment: Most of our build-breaking FxCop rules I've documented on my blog: http://automaticchainsaw.blogspot.com/search/label/FxCop.  Note that these were added slowly over time, and were picked based on our requirements and the current quality of code.

Answer (score 3):

One of the big things we focus on is "no new violations". So we have our [build tool (AnthillPro)](http://www.urbancode.com/html/products/anthillpro/default.html) alert us when there are new violations. I'n not sure if CC.Net does that out of the box, but you can probably play some XML comparison games to get that info.

The approach works pretty nicely in both a new project with few or no initial problems and existing ones. For the existing stuff, take the time at some point to go through the eight thousand complaints and see if there are any you really care about, and then go on from there.

Next up for most groups as they ratchet up is to start deploying the apps and running functional tests.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to investigate [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/). Out of the box it lets you trigger build colours by number of warnings - so, for instance, you could have a green build that has thousands of warnings on one project but a red build for a single warning on another project.

Although it may appear to have a Java focus, Jenkins is very capable for .NET projects, and has many plugins that can analyse e.g. Stylecop XML reports.